# Typescript setState with computed property names

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using Typescript 2.1. I have a React component with state with 2 collections of numbers, I don't want to duplicate the addItem and removeItem methods and want them to be generic. This is the code:

```js
type Collection = 'challenges' | 'disciplines';

type State = {
  lang: string;
  challenges: number[];
  disciplines: number[];
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component<{}, State> {    
  addItem = (collection: Collection, id: number) => {
    this.setState({
      [collection]: [...this.state[collection], id],
    });
  }

  removeItem = (collection: Collection, id: number) => {
    this.setState({
      [collection]: this.state[collection].filter(anId => anId !== id)
    });
  }

  ...

}
```

and this is how I call the methods:

```js
this.addItem('disciplines', id)
```

Right now in addItem method I get compilation error:

> Argument of type '{ [x: string]: number[]; }' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'Pick< State, "lang" | "disciplines"
>   | "challenges">'.
>
> Property 'lang' is missing in type '{ [x: string]:
>   number[]; }'.

Is there a way to properly type this? Thanks!

Comment: I worked around this error using something like this: `this.setState({
      [collection]: this.state[collection].filter(anId => anId !== id)
    } as any);` but there must be some better solution

Comment: @Giladd I found that this is a bug in TypeScript compiler and am now tracking the issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the TypeScript compiler, so we will have to wait for the fix.

The issue for tracking is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948).

Comment: There is a workaround available: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948#issuecomment-336682927

`this.setState({ [key as any]: value });`